# Web API per entity authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, identity

I want to authorize that a user have write access to an entity. I verify this a number of ways.
For example would I check if `entity.PropertyX == user.PropertyY` or `entity.Users.Contains(user))` or some more complex stuff...

Currently I'm doing this directly in the controller action, which no longer is acceptable as the controller count has grown.

```
// example class, pretty much all classes have these properties
// lets assume they do for brevity
public class Foo     
{
    // omitted...
    public int PropertyX { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I want to move this logic - to an attribute for example. But I'm not sure if I can get the same flexibility in an attribute. Because I often/always need the entity in question to check it against the user which is not something that is easily done in an attribute. (to my knowledge)

**Identity**

Currently I'm using my own user table, but I'm planing to change to Identity at some point. I've heard about Claims Based Authorization but I must say I just don't get it yet :( So would claims help me in any way here? As far as I understand it's *just* decorating the user with like an Address field.

**Controller**

```
[CheckIfUserHasAccess]
public IHttpActionResult Post(T entity)
{
    // omitted...
}

[CheckIfUserHasAccess]
public IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, JObject jobj)
{
    // omitted...
}
```

Right... the question part :)
How would you go about implementing *per entity authorization*?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with custom authorization filters. That would enable you to decorate actions with custom attributes that would execute custom authorization logic.

There is some basic info on how to do it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api).